# How can I hide the night time hours in Samsung's "S planner" calendar?

Tags: samsung, calendar

I am using the "S planner" calendar on Samsung galaxy note 2 (Android 4.4.2).
I never make appointments between 12am and 6am and I want to hide these hours from the view. i.e.

[image: screenshot]

Apparently [the same thing can be done in gmail](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2011/11/hide-morning-and-night-hours-in.html)

Today I achieved this by accident - then it restored itself to the default view, now I'm wondering - how can I do it again?

Comment: Note that S Planner is the default calendar app on Samsung devices, not on all Android. Anyway, I'm not sure, but I think you're searching for "List" (or "Agenda" on other calendar apps) on the right tab?

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks for pointing that out! Ive updated question. List view collapses every item to one line. What I'm trying to do is retain the same view - just without those hours

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out - you just double tap in the area where the unused hours are and the view automatically adjusts!

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:] →
[image: IMG:]